# decoding json data into associative array not working

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the following code:

```
$url = "http://myserver/myapp/restapi.php?method=get_list";
$jsondata = curl($url);
print_r($jsondata);
$arrayObjects = json_decode($jsondata, true);
print_r($arrayObjects);
```

The print out of $jsondata  works... but the arrayObjects doesn't print anything.
Ive included just the first "record" of the json data that does get dumped properly:

```
{"263":{"realm":"object","etags":
 [],"id":"263","name":"ddd","label":"","asset_no":null,"objtype_id":"4",
 "r_id":null,"R_name":null,"row_id":null,"Row_name":null,"container_id":null,
 "container_name":null,"has_problems":"no","comment":null,"nports":"3",
 "runs8021Q":"1","itags":[],"dname":"ddd","atags":[{"tag":"$id_263"},
{"tag":"$typeid_4"},{"tag":"$any_object"},{"tag":"$cn_ddd"},{"tag":"$unmounted"},  
 {"tag":"$no_asset_tag"},{"tag":"$runs_8Q"},{"tag":"$untagged"}]}
 },
```

i'm not getting any error messages displayed on the screen either. 
what i did to try to troubleshoot it is to create a new php file that has this json data in it as a string... and then i called json decode.  it works fine.  check out the code below:

```
  <?php

   $jsondata='{"263":{"realm":"object","etags":  
   [],"id":"263","name":"ddd","label":"","asset_no":null,
   "objtype_id":"4","r_id":null,"R_name":null,"row_id":null,
   "Row_name":null,"container_id":null,"container_name":null,
    "has_problems":"no","comment":null,"nports":"3","runs8021Q":"1","itags":     
    [],"dname":"ddd","atags":[{"tag":"$id_263"},
   {"tag":"$typeid_4"},
   {"tag":"$any_object"},{"tag":"$cn_ddd"},{"tag":"$unmounted"},  
   {"tag":"$no_asset_tag"},{"tag":"$runs_8021Q"},{"tag":"$untagged"}]},"187":
   {"realm":"object","etags":[],"id":"187","name":"a-ds-NSM-1",
   "label":"","asset_no":null,"objtype_id":"4","r_id":null,
   "R_name":null,"row_id":null,"Row_name":null,"container_id":null,
   "container_name":null,"has_problems":"no","comment":null,
   "nports":"3","runs8021Q":null,"itags":[],
   "dname":"ss-a-NSM-1","atags":[{"tag":"$id_187"},{"tag":"$typeid_4"},    
   {"tag":"$any_object"},{"tag":"$cn_ss-ds-1"},{"tag":"$unmounted"},   
   {"tag":"$no_asset_tag"},{"tag":"$untagged"}]},
   "123":{"realm":"object","etags":
    [],"id":"123","name":"df","label":"","asset_no":null,
    "objtype_id":"4","r_id":null,"R_name":null,"row_id":null,
   "Row_name":null,"container_id":null,"container_name":null,
   "has_problems":"no","comment":null,"nports":"3",
     "runs8021Q":null,"itags":[],"dname":"df",
    "atags":[{"tag":"$id_123"},{"tag":"$typeid_4"},
      {"tag":"$any_object"},{"tag":"$cn_df"},
   {"tag":"$unmounted"},{"tag":"$no_asset_tag"},{"tag":"$untagged"}]}}';


 print_r(json_decode($jsondata,true));
 ?>
```

any ideas on what's wrong with my code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The print out of $jsondata works... but the arrayObjects doesn't print anything.

That probably means the JSON string is invalid. Make sure you have error_reporting on and display_errors = ON so you can *see the error*. You can also check your PHP error log for the problem.

Comment: yep - ifound a debug statement that was being in included with the json data.